# CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo return null value on iOS 15 Beta, even though VPN Profile is installed

Tags: networking, nehotspothelper, ios15

As per the [document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/systemconfiguration/1614126-cncopycurrentnetworkinfo), the following conditions should be met in order to retrieve network info:

- The app uses Core Location, and has the user’s authorization to use
  location information.
- The app uses the NEHotspotConfiguration API to
  configure the current Wi-Fi network.
- The app has an active VPN
  configuration installed.
- The app has an active NEDNSSettingsManager
  configuration installed.

In our case, the application relies on point 3 i.e installed VPN profile. But, I observed that `CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo` always returns null even though a VPN profile is configured. This works fine with iOS 14.x versions.

I also tried using `fetchCurrentWithCompletionHandler` API. But, ended up with the same result.

Any help/lead would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.